# Google Calendar API v3 Returns "Not Found" when updating an Event

Tags: google-calendar-api

Ok, first off, if this question has been answered, please simply point me in the correct direction.  I have searched and searched without being able to find an answer to what I am running into.

Here's the scenario, I have an application that needs to be able to do the following:

1. Get a list of events for a specified calendar
2. Determine the start and end time of the events
3. If the start time is not correct (i.e. we had events being created at 6:01 instead of 6:00) it needs to adjust the start time
4. Send a POST request to update the start and end times

So far, I have 1-3 accomplished without a problem, my problem is on number 4.  I have a list of events, I have modified the times and created the post request, however, it always comes back with a "Not Found" response, and I'm totally confused.

Here is part of the response I get back when requesting a list of events :

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [kind] => calendar#event
        [etag] => "ZrhdJMCgpoUK_a5fT7XOC6xn46g/Z2NhbDAwMDAxMzU4NjE3MzM1NDE1MDAw"
        [id] => dbqcfrdvkm40tnuvbk46mv1ktg
        [status] => confirmed
        [htmlLink] => ########################
        [created] => 2013-01-19T17:42:15.000Z
        [updated] => 2013-01-19T17:42:15.415Z
        [summary] => #########################
        [description] => ########################
        [location] => Traverse City, MI
        [creator] => stdClass Object
            (
                [email] => ######################
            )

        [organizer] => stdClass Object
            (
                [email] => ##################################
                [displayName] => Kent County
                [self] => 1
            )

        [start] => stdClass Object
            (
                [dateTime] => 2013-01-19T13:01:00-05:00
                [timeZone] => America/New_York
            )

        [end] => stdClass Object
            (
                [dateTime] => 2013-01-19T16:01:00-05:00
                [timeZone] => America/New_York
            )

        [recurrence] => Array
            (
                [0] => RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20130331T000000Z
            )

        [iCalUID] => ###############################
        [sequence] => 0
        [attendees] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [email] => ####################
                        [displayName] => ##############
                        [responseStatus] => needsAction
                    )

            )

        [reminders] => stdClass Object
            (
                [useDefault] => 1
            )

    )
```

as you can see, I am getting the event id without issue, then I turn around and create the post request using the calendar id and the event id I just received

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR ID}/events/dbqcfrdvkm40tnuvbk46mv1ktg?key={API KEY}
```

and this is where I get stuck, the only response I'm getting back is "Not Found" even though the headers being sent with the request look fine

```
Array
(
[url] => https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR ID}/events/dbqcfrdvkm40tnuvbk46mv1ktg?key={API KEY}
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 404
[header_size] => 360
[request_size] => 485
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.364634
[namelookup_time] => 3.0E-5
[connect_time] => 0.08616
[pretransfer_time] => 1.7E-5
[size_upload] => 105
[size_download] => 9
[speed_download] => 24
[speed_upload] => 287
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 105
[starttransfer_time] => 0.3646
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[redirect_url] => 
[request_header] => POST /calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR ID}/events/dbqcfrdvkm40tnuvbk46mv1ktg?key={API KEY} HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {SECURITY TOKEN}, X-JavascriptUser-Agent: HiddenOnes
Content-Length: 105
)
```

If I go to the Google Developer center and use the Events:update test area, this is the url that's generated:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR ID}/events/dbqcfrdvkm40tnuvbk46mv1ktg?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And if I test it from there it works just fine, so I am completely stumped right now so any valid, useful ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your {CALENDAR ID} is invalid. From where are you getting that value?

It is also possible to use the calendar ID of "primary" which defaults to the user's primary calendar.

Also, when updating an event, you should use the `PUT` HTTP verb https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update

Comment: the put was the problem in my case